# How to compare a matrix row by row with specified condition

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, compare, row

I have a data matrix like this:

```
A=[ 5   0   10  15  0.021;
    5   0   15  20  0.011;
    10  15  5   0   0.022;
    15  20  5   0   0.009]
```

I need to compare each row with all of the other rows. The criteria is:
If the 1st and 2nd column of this row is the same as the 3rd and 4th columns of the second row, and if the 3rd and 4th columns of the this row is the same as the 1st and 2nd column of the other row, I need the indices of these two rows.

For example:

```
A = [5  0 10 15  *;
     *  *  *  *  *;
     10 15 5  0  *;
     *  *  *  *  *];
```

As you can see:

- 1st and 2nd element on row 1 are equal to 3rd and 4th of row 3
- 3rd and 4rd element on row 1 are equal to 1st and 2nd of row 3

I do not want change the order of my matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ismember](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) can do that:

```
[~,b]=ismember(A(:,1:4),A(:,[3 4 1 2]),'rows');
ind = find(b);
ind(:,2) = b(ind(:,1));
```

`ind` will contain redundant entries (eg `[1 2]` and also `[2 1]`), because your criterion is symmetrical, you can filter them using:

```
ind = unique(sort(ind,2),'rows')
```

Comment: Hello Gunther,your code works well. I tried to use buildin ismember and unique before, but failed.I guess i need to review their doc in detail. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lei: thx, and indeed: read the documentation and try out for yourself. Once you understand what's going on, it's all pretty easy ;)